# How to enqueue child style after the call of wp_head

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Basically, my problem is the `wp_head()` loaded CSS is the one that is applied and I want it to be the `style.css`. I want to call the enqueue of the child styles after `wp_head()` call. I don't want to add `!important` on my CSS because it's breaking a lot of layout on the site.

[image]

My code to enqueue:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Comment: Can you show the resultant order of CSS loaded? See if [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218610/give-priority-to-child-theme-stylesheet) helps?

Comment: @Raptor, I've edited my question and the sequence + code now is included. What you've link didn't help either.

Comment: In good WP practice, `wp_head()` should not use `<style>` tag to write styles. Consider reviewing the contents in `header.php` in your theme.

Comment: I'm not linking any stylesheet in my header.php, what I've called in header.php is only the wp_head(). I don't want to link any stylesheet on the main php file to minimize requests.

Comment: Please post your full `header.php` and locate any plugins that may add the stylesheet to your WP.

Comment: Find whatever plugin is adding the code to `wp_head`, remove the action that's causing it - reenqueue it properly, and then enqueue your stylesheets with a higher priority number like 99

Comment: Okay, let me find that. I have no clue what is that file since it only showing index:xxx from sources.